# netsh import doesn't work

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, netsh

I'm trying to use netsh to export and then import my network settings.
I managed to export my settings using the command:

```
netsh -c interface dump > c:\settings.txt
```

The file is created, all ok, but when I try importing the file, using:

```
netsh -f c:\settings.txt
```

I get the following:

```
Resetting Global, OK!
Resetting , failed.
Access is denied.

Restart the computer to complete this action.
Resetting Interface, OK!
Resetting , failed.
Access is denied.

Restart the computer to complete this action.
The following command was not found: reset.

Reset of all TCP parameters OK!

The congestionprovider parameter can be set using the
'netsh int tcp set supplemental' command.
The parameter is incorrect.

The following command was not found: reset.
```

I am running my command prompt with administrator privileges on a Windows 8.

I need this because I'm working from more locations and in one of them I have to set some proxy settings and I wanted to automatize this somehow.

**EDIT:** This is the settings file:

```
#========================
# Interface configuration
#========================
pushd interface 
popd
# End of interface configuration

# ----------------------------------
# IPHTTPS Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface httpstunnel
reset
popd
# End of IPHTTPS configuration

# ----------------------------------
# IPv4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ipv4
reset
set global icmpredirects=enabled
popd
# End of IPv4 configuration

# ----------------------------------
# IPv6 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ipv6
reset
set interface interface="Ethernet" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Wi-Fi" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Bluetooth Network Connection" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="(my proxy goes here)" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled mtu=1280 nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection* 12" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="isatap.{A049BA26-6AB7-4880-9D9C-1CD3E579C8E0}" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="isatap.{1B39EAEE-CBD8-406C-928F-FB0F83DC49E5}" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
popd
# End of IPv6 configuration

# ----------------------------------
# ISATAP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface isatap
popd
# End of ISATAP configuration

# ----------------------------------
# 6to4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface 6to4
reset
popd
# End of 6to4 configuration

# ----------------------------------
# ISATAP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface isatap
popd
# End of ISATAP configuration

#========================
# Port Proxy configuration
#========================
pushd interface portproxy
reset
popd
# End of Port Proxy configuration

# ----------------------------------
# TCP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface tcp
reset
set global rss=enabled chimney=disabled autotuninglevel=normal congestionprovider=none ecncapability=disabled timestamps=disabled netdma=disabled dca=disabled initialrto=3000 rsc=enabled
popd
# End of TCP configuration

# ----------------------------------
# Teredo Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface teredo
set state type=client servername=teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com. servervirtualip=0.0.0.0
popd
# End of Teredo configuration

# ----------------------------------
# 6to4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface 6to4
reset
popd
# End of 6to4 configuration
```

Comment: Did you use "Run as administrator"?

Comment: Yes, I opened the command prompt as administrator

Comment: Could you please post settings.txt.

Comment: @harrymc I edited the question and added the contents of the settings.txt file

Comment: I have removed blank lines from it, for readability. I suggest that you break it into parts, starting with per-adapter, so as to find out exactly which error message relates to which command. (The script contains too many incompatible commands to my setup for me to test.)

Answer (score 1):

After looking at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732279(v=ws.10).aspx a few minutes, I'm thinking maybe you should try something like

"netsh -c Interface -f C:\settings.txt".

If that doesn't work, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404790.aspx states "There are functional differences between netsh commands on Windows Server® 2003, Windows Server® 2008, and Windows Server® 2008 R2", & includes some links to other information, including a wealth of information about permissions. That trek starts with the ...cc732279... url above.

Comment: That had better results (the number of errors was smaller) but still didn't did the job. I'll look into the links you added. Thanks